# How to allow alphanumeric and certain special characters in angularjs using regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question might be a simple one, but looks complex when trying to use regex pattern for this.

I have a textarea and I'm trying to allow alphanumeric characters and only 5 certain special characters like `. , ' " :`

Other special characters should be disabled when typing.

I have tried to use `ng-pattern` from angularjs, but when I start typing special characters other than allowed one, it is not disabled.

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,:'"]*$/">
```

The main problem is when I try to allow `' "` both of these certain special characters, facing syntax issue in ng-pattern.

I'm expecting a simple solution using only regex in ng-pattern.

I'm missing somewhere, can someone help on this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows="5" cols="50" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,:'"]*$/">
  
</textarea>
```

Comment: By the way, `ng-pattern` won't prevent disallowed characters from entered—it'll set form validation errors though. If you want to do the former, you'll want to hook into `$parsers` and `$formatters` of `NgModelController`.

Comment: You may refer to this JSfiddle: https://plnkr.co/edit/802qL8JbvaS5djLQKku4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to html encode the double quote character inside the pattern, like this:

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,:&apos;&quot;]*$/"
```

Currently the pattern ends when it reaches the first double quote.

For safety, also html encode the single quote.

**Edit**, I had made a mistake, now it should Work.

Comment: Thanks, how I can prevent typing other special characters?

Comment: You may refer to this JSfiddle: https://plnkr.co/edit/802qL8JbvaS5djLQKku4?p=preview